# Android Dependency on Particular Snapshot Version

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, picasso

I am trying to point to a particular 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT version of the Picasso library in Sonatype's snapshots repository [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT).

The Gradle version I am using is `4.0.1` and I am using version `2.3.3` of the Android Gradle plugin. I am following the directions from the [Gradle 2.4 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes.html#depending-on-a-particular-maven-snapshot-version) on how to do this by specifiying the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:3.0.0-20170712.175103-16'
}
```

The behavior that I am seeing is that the dependency is resolved correctly, but it seems to fail to pick up the artifact and add it to the project. So when I do a build, it does not complain about finding the dependency, but during the compile step, it fails to find any of the classes defined by the Picasso library.

Comment: Created a issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/63992133

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I didn't understand how you are working on gradle version **4.0.1**. Second thing is that your **build tool** version is also not understandable. and coming to your question, if you are using gradle version below **2.4**, it won't work due a **bug**. (You can check it [Here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2784)). **Update** your gradle version and you are good to go.